# How to write a query for select require columns and count from different tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am working in mvc3 here i need some help please

## here i have some tables like(BugId)

BugID      Title     Description         ProjectId  Version     BuildNumber   EmployeId CategoryID  CreatedDate  SeverityID PriorityID ReleasePhaseID TypeID

## 2      Banking   bankingapplication   1    new version  new build no    1    1      00:00:00.00    1          1          1      1

(Projects Table)

=======================================================

```
 Projectid  ProjectName Description        Status

1   Finance     This is Finance Project    Active
2   Uniformatic This is Finance Project    Active
3   ProDuct     This is Finance Project    InActive
4   Cloud       This is Finance Project    INActive
5   Banking     This is Finance Project    Progress
```

## 6   Ecommerce   This is Finance Project    Active

RealesePhase (table)

====================================================================

```
 ReleasePhaseID    ReleasePhase

1       DEV
2       QA
3       Alpha
4       Beta
```

## 5       Live

Tostatus(table)

===================================================

```
ToStatusId        Tostatus

1       New
2       Assigned
3       Fixed
4       Re-Opened
5       Closed
6       Deffered
```

## 7       Not a Bug

## Bughistory (Table)

BugHistoryID          BugID    FixedByID  AssignedTo        Resolution           FromStatus     ToStatus

```
5                  2         1            1     this is my banking     New           New
7                  2         1            1     this assignto res                km,l
```

======================================================================================================

here i have these tables now i have to write a query to select ProjectName(dropdown)
And (ReleasePhase)  from it (open)(closed)(fixedBy)

in Bugs table Bugs will be log (insert) from it so now we have to select Project Name & ReleasePhase as dropdown if we select the project name i should get the No of Bugs we have for it (counting)

from it like 
(view) should like this

=====================================================================

ProjectName  RealesePhase  openBugs  ClosedBugs   fixedBy

```
                 1         New         EmployeName
                 2         Assigned    EmployeName
                 3         Fixed       EmployeName
                 4         Re-Opened   EmployeName
```

======================================================================

so plz help me to write a query count and show the how many bugs Employee inserted and how many are released and how many closed

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use a stored Procedure for this..and i think you need the count of Bugs as per your status table and Releasephase and ProjectId..this is what i figured by seeing your question hope it helps you....

```
 Create procedure [dbo].[ProjectReports]
 (
 @ProjectID int,
 @ReleasePhaseID int
 )
 as
 begin
 select distinct projectName,ReleasePhase,
(Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='New')) as Newbugs,
(Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and  ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and 
bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Assigned')) as Assignedbugs,
(Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Fixed')) as Fixedbugs,
(Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Re-Opened')) as Reopenedbugs,
(Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Closed')) as Closedbugs,
(Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID  and
 bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Deffered')) as Defferedbugs,
(Select  COUNT(1) from Bugs where ProjectId=a.ProjectId and ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID and
 bugid in (select BugID from BugHistory where [status]='Not a Bug')) as NotaBug
 from Bugs a
inner join Projects p on p.ProjectId=a.ProjectId
 inner join ReleasePhase Rp on rp.ReleasePhaseID=a.ReleasePhaseID
where a.ProjectId=@ProjectID and a.ReleasePhaseID=@ReleasePhaseID
end
```